# Find out forward URL in Java

Tags: java, url-rewriting

If I visit f.e. http://www.euroverlag.de/ I will be redirected to http://www.euroverlag.de/gambio/

How can i find out the forward URL? For real Redirections I m using:

```
URLConnection con = new URL(http://www.euroverlag.de).openConnection();
con.connect();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
con.getURL().toString(); // retuns the redirection URL
is.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by find out the forward URL?

Comment: i have the start URL like http://www.euroverlag.de and want to get http://www.euroverlag.de/gambio/